# C# CRM m:n relationship

Tags: c#, many-to-many, dynamics-crm, crm

In my CRM database, I have two entity groups, A and B, linked by an m:n-relationship. There are many instances of entity A each linked to several instances of entity B. For a particular entity, let's say an an instance of entity A, how do I get all the linked instances of entity B?

```
var service = new OrganizationService(_connection);

var retrieveRequest = new RetrieveMultipleRequest();

retrieveRequest.Query = new QueryExpression
    {
        EntityName = "new_A",
        ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true)
    }; 

var crmReponse = (RetrieveMultipleResponse)service.Execute(retrieveRequest);
```

When viewing crmResponse in debugging mode, I see all instances of entity A, but I do not see anything within the RelatedInstances property. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: After getting the first answer, I adapted my code as follows:

```
var linkEntities = new LinkEntity { 

    LinkFromEntityName = "new_A",
    LinkToEntityName = "new_B"

};

var retrieveRequest = new RetrieveMultipleRequest();

var query = new QueryExpression
{
    EntityName = "new_A",
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true)
};

query.LinkEntities.Add(linkEntities);

retrieveRequest.Query = query;

var crmReponse = (RetrieveMultipleResponse)service.Execute(retrieveRequest);
```

Now I get an error, though:

> No system many-to-many relationship exists between
>   new_customer_system_machine_type and
>   new_customer_system_machine_check.  If attempting to link through a
>   custom many-to-many relationship ensure that you provide the from and
>   to attributes.

However, when I created that many-to-many-relationship, I did not specify any attribute names, it was merely between the entities. What am I doing wrong?

Also, my `RetrieveMultipleRequest` class does not have the property `ReturnDynamicEntities`

Comment: CRM 4, at least that's the version of the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the LinkFromAttributeName and the LinkToAttributeName.  These are going to be the attributes of the from and to entities that contain the matching key values.

Comment: But the many-to-many-relationship did not generate any keys for neither of the entities. Additionally, when I specify a made-up attribute name, it throws an error because that attribute name does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can find answer in this [blog post](http://andreaswijayablog.blogspot.com/2011/02/crm-entity-relationship-many-to-many-nn.html). There described two ways:
  - [RetrieveMultipleRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb929303.aspx) with [LinkEntity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb890621.aspx) class;
  - [Fetch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb928434.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. It still does not work though, could you please read my edit?